# Custom reactive decoder in Spring Boot missing characters in Inputstream

Tags: java, spring-boot, python-requests, spring-webflux

**Update:**

It works if I call `encode()` on the string passed to the requests client.

```py
response: Response = requests.request('POST', 
   "http://localhost:8080/api", 
   headers={
     'Accept': "application/ld+json",
     'Content-Type': "application/ld+json" 
   }, 
   data=content.encode()
)
```

I don't really understand how the encoding (in this case to "UTF-8") changes the behaviour on the server side (since Wireshark showed that the complete String was transmitted), but it seems to work for now.

---

I have the following custom decoder to parse JSON-LD from requests:

```java
    public Mono<Foo> decodeToMono(Publisher<DataBuffer> buffers, ResolvableType elementType, MimeType mimeType, Map<String, Object> hints) {
      return DataBufferUtils.join(publisher)
                .flatMap(dataBuffer -> {
                    try (InputStream is = dataBuffer.asInputStream(true)) {
                        var result = new String(is.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        log.info(result);

                        // some rdf logic here
                        return Mono.just(...);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.warn("Failed to parse request of mimetype '{}'", mimeType);
                        return Mono.error(e);
                    }
                });
    }
```

I call the api using the python requests library. The logs print a valid json document such as (very simplified)

```json
[   
    {
    "@id": "_:Nf3d46019bcde490484128dfd01ebca40",
    "@type": [
      "https://schema.org/DefinedTerm"
    ],
    "https://schema.org/identifier": [
      {
        "@value": "tag:arithemtica+integra"
      }
    ],
    "https://schema.org/termCode": [
      {
        "@value": "Arithemtica integra"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Printing the string in the StringWriter from the java decoder will result in something like

```json
[   
    {
    "@id": "_:Nf3d46019bcde490484128dfd01ebca40",
    "@type": [
      "https://schema.org/DefinedTerm"
    ],
    "https://schema.org/identifier": [
      {
        "@value": "tag:arithemtica+integra"
      }
    ],
    "https://schema.org/termCode": [
      {
        "@value": "Arithemt
```

Due to the missing characters at the end, the decoding results in the exception message
`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Array (start marker at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 6350])`

The cutoff seems to be arbitrary. It's always very close to the end (something like 6350 of 6356 total chars in the valid json or 7921 of 7931)

I assume it has something to do with the streams cutting of early, but I honestly have no idea where to start digging for the root cause.

Comment: Where does `IOUtils.copy` come from ? If you want to decode InputStream content fully to text, you could try to replace your StringWriter and IOUtils.copy with just `var txt = new String(is.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: The [method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) is part of Apache's common-io. 

I checked if the issue lies there (see updated code), but the String is still cut off at the end.